# post multiple images combining individual blobs javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, image

I have written a code to resize images from javascript and currently I'm sending them one by one using ajax to my controller. So I'm running a for loop and inside that the resized image come to a variable name "photo" and I'm using following javascript to upload it,

```
var upload = function (photo, callback) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('photo', photo);
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState === 4) {
            callback(request.response);
        }
    }
    request.open('POST', '../Test/process');
    request.responseType = 'json';
    request.send(formData);
};
```

please note that this function is getting called inside a for loop, which means this is uploading one photo at a time.(Calling process function for every photo uploaded)

But what I wanted to do is upload photos at once (Calling process function once to upload multiple photos).

So what I did was pushing every resized image to an array and sending it using the above function. But then it sends the array as a post (as a $_POST, before that it was sent as $_FILES as expected) and also it did not contain the desired images.

```
var arrayImages = [];
var files = document.getElementById("fileToUploadId").files;
for (var i in files) {
    arrayImages.push(resizedFile); //creating array of resized image objects
}
```

So what should I do to post these resized images as an array to the controller?

i.e **how can I send multiple javascript processed images to controller as a normal multiple image upload? photos send to controller as an array and could get called from**

```
$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$imageNum]
```

Comment: you want to send actual images or base64 string of image?

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge to answer that. Anyway Im using

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge to answer that. Anyway Im using
 canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);
to create the resized image.

Comment: so instead of sending image each time,why can't you add it as a base 64string in array send whole array as a string .

Comment: can you plz tell me what are passing to upload function as photo(base 64 string or file) ?

Comment: I'm sending a Blob object (it shows values of size and type attributes with several methods when I print it in the console). that object has created from a canvas using drawImage function. 
So I think I'm sending a file.

Comment: And thank you for your other idea, I'll try to learn about base 64 string array and implement it. :D

Comment: you are always welcome :)